# Xamarin Ios screen reload issue

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have recently created a ios application using Xamarin. The aplication is writen is C#. The application is a little complex and big. It has a lot of dynamic menus.
I have noticed a problem that I could not solve it. When I want to remove a sub  view and add another subview sometimes, especially it the system is high loaded the first subviews is not removed but the second is add and they overlap.

I have tried a lot of things to remove the sub view from view:

```
sub.RemoveFromSuperview();

InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
sub.RemoveFromSuperview();
});
```

or

```
view.WillRemoveSubView(sub);
sub.RemoveFromSuperview();
```

but still sometimes work and sometimes it does not work. Is there any problem, with my approach or there is some problems with IOS. Is there any way to fix this. This problem appears in iPhone and iPad too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you adding the views or navigating? That might help in figuring out why they won't remove.

Comment: In my view there is a switch button and when the switch changes to OFF I want to remove same UI components (UITextField, UIImageVIew).
I always add them the same 
      this.view.addSubview(firstField)